# How to find the index of an object in a list of objects? VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, oop

I am creating a method FindPerson which searches for a given name in a list of objects and returns the index in the list of the object with this name if found, otherwise it returns -1.

```
    Public Class TPerson
        Private Name As String
        Private Address As String
        Private Age As Integer

        Public Sub New()
            Name = "x"
            Address = "x"
            Age = 0
        End Sub

        ……

    End Class


    Public Class TGroup
         Private Group As List(Of TPerson)
         Private GroupSize As Integer

         Public Sub New(size As Integer)
             GroupSize = size
             Group = New List(Of TPerson)
         End Sub


         Public Sub FindPerson(findname As String)
            Dim index As Integer 
            index = Group.FindIndex(findname) 'error
         End Sub
     End Class
```

The output should be an index in the list, however when I run the program I get the error: BC30311  Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to 'Predicate(Of TPerson)'

I am not quite sure how to fix this any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

How exactly do you expect the `FindIndex` method to know what to do with that `String` that you are passing in?  You seem to assume that it will know that it represents a name and that it needs to match an item by `Name` property but how do you think it's going to do that?  Why do you think it would match on `Name` rather than `Address`?

As the error message says, you need to provide a `Predicate` which is a delegate that takes an object of type `T` and returns a `Boolean`.  In your case, `T` is `TPerson` and the `Boolean` needs to indicate whether `findname` matches its `Name` property. The simplest way to do that is with a Lambda expression:

```
Dim index = Group.FindIndex(Function(person) person.Name = findname)
```

You could do it with a named method and a delegate if you wanted to but it would be more long-winded and it would mean getting the `findname` value in by some convoluted means.  If you read the documentation for the `FindIndex` method (which you should have done before posting here) you can find an example of that sort of thing.

Comment: TPerson has Private fields so person.Name is not accessible. I think the OP needs to change the TPerson class to have Public Properties instead of Private fields.

Comment: @Mary, I guess I must have just assumed that those fields were public properties as it seems the logical option. I agree that the OP should almost certainly make them so.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments and helping me find a solution, I am fairly new to OOP and didn't fully understand how to use Predicates. jmcilhinney - I acknowledge that the code I displayed does not specify to the computer which attribute/property should be checked, however as my attributes were private I didn't know how to communicate this.